# How do I return To Cell A1 after clicking a button?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a button at the bottom of my excel sheet that generates another sheet ounce clicked. That function works fine but I need to return to the top of the sheet after I click the button and not to the new Sheet.

What kind of VBA code will be used to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this sample ..

```
Application.GoTo ActiveSheet.Range("A1"),True
```

Comment: @MikeBarnes .. you should try this

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Sheets(1).Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: This assumes that the sheet containing the button is the first sheet in the workbook but that is not known so this may be a working solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New_sheet_name").Range("A1")
```

Comment: I want to return the View back to A1!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the button click sub. When you click the button this will check what sheet you are currently on, run your code, and when it is done return to the previous sheet with A1 selected in view.

```
Sub Example()
   Dim PrevSheet as Worksheet

   PrevSheet = ActiveSheet

   'Your code that does stuff, creates a new sheet etc..

   PrevSheet.Select
   Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```